# Unable to run a windows task that makes https request under SYSTEM account

Tags: windows, batch-file, jmeter, taskscheduler, datadog

I have created a windows cmd file that calls three independent bat files. I want to create a windows task that calls this cmd file and runs every 5 minutes. The problem is that this task runs perfectly fine only when I'm logged into the system. *But I'm unable to make this task continue to run "whether I'm logged in or not"*.

I even asked my colleague to login to that machine and run this task under his account - it worked. I created a local admin user on that machine, logged in as that user, tried to run this task - it did not work - the script waits forever while post_results.bat. I even tried to schedule a jenkins job that basically does the same thing - it did not work - the jenkins job waits forever while post_results.bat (I killed the jenkins job after waiting for ~20 min).

Here is a summary of what these tasks are doing:

**run_all.cmd**

```
call "run_test.bat"
call "post_results.bat"
call "clean.bat"
```

**run_test.bat** - executes a jmeter script

```
C:\Users\Administrator\LS2\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\jmeter -n -t api_strategy_synthetic_tests.jmx -JTestEnv=amer1 -l Result_log.jtl
```

**post_results.bat** - calls a python script that posts the jmeter test results to datadog

```
python post_jmeter_results_to_datadog.py Result_log.jtl
```

**post_jmeter_results_to_datadog.py** - uses the datadog python api to post metrics to datadog

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import pandas as pd
from datadog import initialize, api

options = {
    'api_key': <API_KEY>,
    'app_key': <APPLICATION_KEY>
}
initialize(**options)

jtl_file = sys.argv[1]
df = pd.read_csv(jtl_file)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    tag = "success:" + str(row['success'])
    api.Metric.send(
        metric=row['label'],
        points=[(row['timeStamp']/1000,row['elapsed'])],
        tags=[tag]
        )
```

**clean.bat** - deletes the jmeter test result files

```
rmdir /s /q "errors"
del "jmeter.log"
del "Result_log.jtl"
```

All I need is to be able to run this task every 5 minutes. If anyone is able to see what I'm doing wrong and points that out... I'd be really grateful.

Comment: If you're running a script from a different account you need to ensure that the script specifies it's working directories or uses full paths. _(the `.cmd` and `.bat` files you've posted, don't do that!)_

Comment: Thank you Compo. That was one problem. Another problem was the proxy settings... both my and my colleague's account were set to a particular proxy host while the SYSTEM account had that proxy disabled. Once I turned the proxy back on... it started working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

You can create one PowerShell script to execute your Batch scripts remotely.
And Even you can schedule your PowerShell script using Windows Task Scheduler which will run as per your settings.